# unclear use of a parameter $\rho$ in complicated set theory

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

[Here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0168007205001399/1-s2.0-S0168007205001399-main.pdf?_tid=6a398548-29db-11e7-972d-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1493140981_79b3d7a1c94f8d6ebc3a1584cd05669c) in the definition 4.1.2 (e)
Shelah says Sol$_\eta$={$\rho\in R$:the set...}, *but* $\rho$ does *not* appear
further on the r.h.s.,i.e. $\rho$ is mentioned only *once*. This is apparently incorrect,some typo is there!

Comment: Could be nice if you also specify the page number...

Comment: It's page 156,the definition 4.1. right above claim 4.2.

Comment: Without reading in detail, I'd guess it $\rho$ should be $\eta$.

Comment: You've confirmed my guess that $\rho$ is incorrect. Thanks!